# Why TrimLeft doesn't work as expected?

Tags: go

I've expected tag to be "account" but it is "ccount". Why is "a" removed?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    s := "refs/tags/account"
    tag := strings.TrimLeft(s, "refs/tags")
    fmt.Println(tag)
}
```

[Run](http://play.golang.org/p/M1p_WUi_r2)

Comment: You're probably interested in `strings.Split`.

Comment: actually it's strings.Index. No need for a split.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is working [as documented](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimLeft):

> TrimLeft returns a slice of the string s *with all leading Unicode
>   code points contained in cutset removed*

Because there's an 'a' in the first argument (the cutset) the leading 'a' in account is removed

Comment: ah... it seems it doesn't really work as expected. What I need seems to be strings.Index[]

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat Right, TrimLeft is a counter-intuitive named method. Index is okay, but may not be as convenient and intuitive as TrimPrefix. TrimPrefix could be also necessary in some cases so it's good to know.

Comment: I still don't get it. From the docs, I can't tell the difference betwen TrimLeft and TrimPrefix.

Comment: @djeikyb See the second argument of 'TrimPrefix' and 'TrimLeft'. TrimPrefix receive 'prefix string' but TimeLeft receive 'cutset string'.

Answer (score 13):

Use TrimPrefix instead of TrimLeft

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    s := "refs/tags/account"
    tag := strings.TrimPrefix(s, "refs/tags/")
    fmt.Println(tag)
}
```

Please notice that following TrimLeft calls will result the same "fghijk
" string:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "/abcde/fghijk"
    tag := strings.TrimLeft(s, "/abcde")
    fmt.Println(tag)    
    tag = strings.TrimLeft(s, "/edcba")
    fmt.Println(tag)
}
```

So TrimLeft is not the method which fits your needs. I guess it's impossible to use it in the example you've given to get the result you expect.